# Reactive .NET retry policy

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I haven't found a good code example for a reactive retry operator with a retry strategy that was good enough for my needs. So I tried to make my own. It seems to work in my tests but I would really appreciate some feedback. (C# 8.0)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace Fncy.Helpers
{
    public static class ObeservableHelpers
    {
        public delegate TimeSpan? NextRetryDelay(int previousRetryCount, TimeSpan elapsedTime, Exception retryReason);

        public static IObservable<TSource> RetryAfterDelay<TSource>(
            this IObservable<TSource> source,
            NextRetryDelay retryDelay,
            IScheduler scheduler = null)
        {
            if (retryDelay == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(retryDelay));
            scheduler ??= Scheduler.Default;
            return source.RetryWhen(errors =>
            {
                var retryStart = scheduler.Now;
                int previousRetryCount = 0;
                return errors.SelectMany(ex =>
                {
                    var delay = retryDelay(previousRetryCount++, scheduler.Now - retryStart, ex);
                    return delay == null
                        ? Observable.Throw<Unit>(ex)
                        : Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(delay.Value, scheduler);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```